# Error creating application with node.js

Tags: ibm-cloud, broker

I am in the US South Bluemix region. I received the following error when trying to create an application using the "SDK for Node.js" boilerplate:

> BXNUI2032E: An error occurred when contacting Cloud Foundry to create a resource. Resource: service_bindings. Cloud Foundry message: "Service broker error: {"description"=>"Error 500 received from broker url http://env5monitoringservicebroker.ng.bluemix.net/v2/service_instances/61529633-1ded-4c6f-b725-e6112dc25516/service_bindings/6d213979-dae2-4cfb-ae54-1600cdfc31e6"}." See the Troubleshooting topics in the IBM Bluemix Documentation to check service status, review troubleshooting information, or for information about getting help

I am not sure how to troubleshoot this problem. According to [this site](http://estado.ng.bluemix.net/?cm_mc_uid=76873886244114382885670&cm_mc_sid_50200000=1444947980), the `Node.JS runtime` is up. So what can be causing the above issue?

Comment: Are you trying to bind a service to the application?  How exactly did you create the application?  I just deployed an application using that runtime and it was fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message that you see is due to a problem with the `Monitoring and Analytics` service that was seen yesterday. This is now resolved.

When you create the `SDK for Node.js` boilerplate then it will also provision a `Cloudant NoSQL DB` and also the `Monitoring and Analytics` service in addition to the Node.js runtime.

Comment: Thank you. It works today. So what is the best website to see the status of Bluemix? Is it the link in my post? Is there a website that would have shown yesterday that it was not possible to create an application with the "SDK For Node.js" boilerplate because of the extra services provisioned?

Comment: The status page you mentioned in your post is the best place for up-to-the minute status on Bluemix platform and services. You can go to https://status.ng.bluemix.net for notifications of upcoming service and platform maintenance, and possible outages.